# Why javascript adds %3 to my GET request ?

Tags: javascript

I'm very new to java script, so it's might be a noob question.

I have a page located on my computer, can be accessed by : 
21.81.91.103:8945

When I press something I want to send a GET request with some parameters to the IP. so I've used:

`window.location.host`
I also tried : `window.location.hostname + \":\" + location.port`

From some reason the request is sent to : 
%321.81.91.103:8945

I have no idea from where the %3 comes from.

The relevant code snippet is :

```
  function callURL()
  {
  $.get( window.location.hostname , { red: $( "#red" ).slider( "value" ), green : $( "#green" ).slider( "value" ), blue: $( "#blue" ).slider( "value" )});
  }
```

Another interesting fact is when I load the page, and type:`window.location.host` in chrome console I get the correct result (without the %3).

You can see the page here if it helps : 
https://jsfiddle.net/bzx0h06o/4/

Comment: Weird. I'd start with doing console.log('window.location.hostname')  right before you use it to see whether it looks good there or not.

Answer (score 2):

If a URL doesn't start with a protocol or '/', then it's treated as a relative URL. If you're at http://example.com, then `window.location.hostname` is equal to "example.com", and making a request for "example.com" will resolve to "http://example.com/example.com". Just make a request for "/" instead, which will resolve to "http://example.com":

```
function callURL() {
  $.get("/", { red: $( "#red" ).slider( "value" ), green : $( "#green" ).slider( "value" ), blue: $( "#blue" ).slider( "value" )});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The %3 is in fact a percent-encoded digit 2 ("%32").
**%32**1.81.91.103:8945 decodes to **2**1.81.91.103:8945.

But I don't know why the first character (and only the first one) is encoded.